# Is it valid to change the order of the words in the following case?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

> **Ray fitted on Tom the hat** he occasionally wore on dates.
>
> **Ray fitted the hat on Tom,** the one he occasionally wore on dates.

Is the order grammatical in both cases? Is it normal or common to change the order of words like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can switch but your second sentence has a comma splice. Use a semi colon or a conjunction to fix it.

> Ray fitted the hat on Tom; the one he occasionally wore on dates.

Comment: I think " the one he occasionally wore on dates" isn't a full sentence?

Comment: I'm fairly sure that clause can exist on its own. I suggested the semi colon because when I read your second sentence, it didn't sound right to my ears without a semi-colon. Unless another user brings some insight, I'd play it safe with a semi-colon.